# Slow serial communication with arduino and response on the application?

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper-motor

Currently, I'm doing a project as I want to use my Arduino Mega 2560 as an interface to my computer with a photo interrupter and stepper motor. So I need to send some commands and data to the Arduino from my PC. However, after upload the code to the board, I found out the serial communication of the Arduino quite slow. In fact, the moment after the code done uploading, my command in the Serial Monitor takes almost a second to execute. Below is the details about the code:-

```
    // Include the Arduino Stepper Library
#include <Stepper.h>

// Number of steps per output rotation
const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;

// Create Instance of Stepper library
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 12, 11, 10, 9);

int val;
int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
  // set the speed at 200rpm:

  myStepper.setSpeed(200);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  val = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(val);

  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
  counter = counter + 1;
  Serial.println(counter);

if (val > 200){
    Serial.println("it is running");

   } else {
    myStepper.setSpeed(0);
    Serial.println(counter);

   }


}
```

Any help so much appreciated.

Comment: so why not set a higher baud rate?

Comment: About a second between opening the serial monitor and the first response arriving? Yes. That's normal. That's called the bootloader executing. If you want faster then use a board that doesn't use a serial bootloader, or delete the bootloader and program the board with a hardware programmer.